# MessageSummaryItems.PreviewText Clarification

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

We're making use of the newly added MessageSummaryItems.PreviewText feature.  Thank you!!

On issue is:  sometimes the PreviewText contains HTML links?  From reading through the source I see this in ImapFolderFetch.cs

> var body = message.TextBody ?? message.HtmlBody;

So this is saying:  use the Plaintext version, if it exists, then use the HTML version?

Therefore if I see links in the preview, I can assume no Plaintext version is available?

Our problem with this is:

If our message only has an HTML version,  We could strip the links from the message in our code, but there are only 256 characters of it. In many cases, there will be nothing left to display.

As per your TODO:  Using the CONVERT extension would be a better approach but, as far as I can tell its not supported by Gmail?

A fall back would be:

If we could set the preview length for both HTML and Plaintext individually,  then we could say, If you only have an HTML version give me 1K of it and i'll strip out the links on the client.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few IMAP servers support the CONVERT extension which is the main reason I didn't implement it.

The PreviewText feature is an attempt at adding a convenience feature to fetch the first 256 bytes of each message body in batched requests in order to minimize latency, but no matter what I do, it's not guaranteed to be useful (since there could be a ton of markup before any real text is included in HTML).

If I were to split text and html messages into 2 different batches so that I could request different sizes for each, then it would be less efficient and might take significantly longer to fetch, so I'm not sure if it's really worth it. The less I'm able to batch at a time, the less useful the feature becomes compared to implementing your own loop over the list of messages and downloading your own specified chunk size. one message at a time.

My suggestion would be to use the PreviewText feature and for the rare messages where the 256 bytes isn't enough, perform a `folder.GetStream()` on them.

Comment: Forgot that it would require two different requests.  I agree. Do the best we can with 256 messages and if any are too short make a special request.. Thanks.